# I can't get the following link to be clickable, is my syntax correct?

Tags: php, hyperlink

I found this email script on the internet, which allows me to send a file attachment but I can't seem to get the link highlighted or shown as a clickable link.

I am just wondering if my syntax is correct here? From my understanding, I thought that a '.' is only to add on variables, so for this line of code, should I use a dot or comma?

I have updated my code to the following but it still does not work. I still can't get the link to be clickable:

```
$to = $email;
$link = "http://localhost/loginsystem/includes/activatepremium.php?email=".htmlspecialchars($mailTo)."&activatetoken=".htmlspecialchars($token)."";
//sender
$from = 'pianocourse101@hotmail.com';
$fromName = 'PianoCourse101';

//email subject
$subject = 'Activate your Level 3 Monthly Membership!'; 

//attachment file path
$file = "codexworld.pdf";

//email body content
$htmlContent = "<h1>PHP Email with Attachment by CodexWorld</h1>
              <p>Thank you for registering with pianocourse101! At pianocourse101, your child can now learn how to play the piano right from the comfort of your own home! \n\nOur lessons are based from the Bastien Piano Basics series because it is both fun and educational for your child. \n\nHowever, you must activate your Premium membership account by clicking on the link below: \n\n ".$link."
              </p>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all add spaces so it will be easier to read as:

```
$htmlContent = "<h1>PHP Email with Attachment by CodexWorld</h1>
       <p>Thank you for registering with pianocourse101! At pianocourse101, your child can now learn how to play the piano right from the comfort of your own home! \n\nOur lessons are based from the Bastien Piano Basics series because it is both fun and educational for your child. \n\nHowever, you must activate your Premium membership account by clicking on the link below: \n\n http://localhost/loginsystem/includes/activatepremium.php?email=" . htmlspecialchars($mailTo) . "&activatetoken=" . htmlspecialchars($token) . "</p>";
```

Second, "." is the right syntax to concat string in php.

Last, adding link in html tag is used by `href`.

Try this:

```
$link = "http://localhost/loginsystem/includes/activatepremium.php?email=" . htmlspecialchars($mailTo) . "&activatetoken=" . htmlspecialchars($token);
$href = "<a href=\"$link\">ClickMe</a>";
```

Now add the `$href` to `$htmlContent` as:

```
$htmlContent = "<h1>PHP Email with Attachment .... // add all the rest of the content
      ... by clicking on the link below: $href \n\n </p>";
```

Comment: There's a `"` too much in `htmlspecialchars($token)";`. And a `;` missing in the next line

Comment: http://localhost/loginsystem/includes/activatepremium.php?email=".htmlspecialchars($mailTo)."&activatetoken=".htmlspecialchars($token).";
                                      </p>";

Comment: owever, you must activate your Premium membership account by clicking on the link below: \n\n http://localhost/loginsystem/includes/activatepremium.php?email=".htmlspecialchars($mailTo)."&activatetoken=".htmlspecialchars($token).";

Comment: I will try it your way but just wondering if the above should work without putting it in a $href

Comment: @musician888 Using the `href` is the right way to add the link. Why aren't you want to use it?

Comment: I totally forgot that I need the a href in html output... I got it working now... cheers!

Comment: @musician888 if it is working for you please mark the answer as accepted so other may use it also (the v mark near the naswer)

Comment: @musician888 At the left side of my answer there is a number (the answer score) and two arrows (up-vote and down-vote) - under the down-vote triangle the is grey "v" mark

Comment: thanks and I forgot to include the anchor tag to make it work